# Accept Friendship is not updating (Mutual Friendships)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, attributes

I'm going through one of Treehouse's videos on Mutual Friendship. The problem that I'm having is when the user clicks on the '**Accept Friendship**' button a flash message is displayed stating that they are now friends with me. However, it does not update on the users Friends page. It still shows that the user has a '**Friendship requested**' and to accept it. Somehow it is not updating.

It shows that the friendship started on my end however, it wont update for the other user. It still says that the person has a Friendship request. Please see code below. Thank you in advance.

I'm not sure if this has something to do with  **mutual_friendship.update_attribute(:state, 'accepted')**

**User_Friendship Model**

```
class UserFriendship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friend, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'friend_id'

   state_machine :state, initial: :pending do

    after_transition on: :accept, do: [:send_acceptance_email, :accept_mutual_friendship!]

    state :requested

    event :accept do
        transition any => :accepted
    end
  end

  def self.request(user1, user2)
    transaction do
        friendship1 = create!(user: user1, friend: user2, state: 'pending')
        friendship2 = create!(user: user2, friend: user1, state: 'requested')

        friendship1.send_request_email
        friendship1
    end    
  end


 def send_request_email
    UserNotifier.friend_requested(id).deliver
 end

 def send_acceptance_email
    UserNotifier.friend_request_accepted(id).deliver
 end

 def mutual_friendship
 self.class.where({user_id: friend_id, friend_id: user_id}).first
 end

  def accept_mutual_friendship!
  # Grab the mutual friendship and update the state without using the state machine, so as
  # not to invoke callbacks.
  mutual_friendship.update_attribute(:state, 'accepted')
  end 
end
```

**UserFriendship Controller**

```
class UserFriendshipsController < ApplicationController
 before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index
  @user_Friendships = current_user.user_friendships.all
  end   

 def accept
  @user_friendship = current_user.user_friendships.find(params[:id])
  if @user_friendship.accept_mutual_friendship!
  flash[:success] = "You are now friends with #{@user_friendship.friend.name}"
  redirect_to user_friendships_path
 else
  flash[:error] = "That friendship could not be accepted"
  redirect_to user_friendships_path
  end
end

 def new
 if params[:friend_id]
   @friend = User.find(params[:friend_id])
   raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound if @friend.nil?
    @user_friendship = current_user.user_friendships.new(friend: @friend)
 else
  flash[:error] = "Friend required"
  end
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  render file: 'public/404', status: :not_found
 end

  def create
  if params[:user_friendship] && params[:user_friendship].has_key?(:friend_id)
  @friend = User.find(params[:user_friendship][:friend_id])
  @user_friendship = UserFriendship.request(current_user, @friend)
  if @user_friendship.new_record?
    flash[:error] = "There was a problem creating this friend request."
  else
    flash[:success] = "Friend request sent."
  end
  redirect_to user_path(@friend)
 else
  flash[:error] = "Friend required"
  redirect_to root_path
   end
 end

def edit
@user_friendship = current_user.user_friendships.find(params[:id])
@friend = @user_friendship.friend
end

 def user_friendship
  params.require(:user_friendship).permit(:user_id, :friend_id, :user, :friend, :state, :user_friendship)
  end    
 end
```

**User/Index**

```
<div class="page-header">
<h1> Friends </h1>
</div>
   <% @user_Friendships.each do |friendship| %>
          <% friend = friendship.friend %>
      <div id="<%= dom_id(friendship) %>" class="friend row">
       <div class="span1">

       </div>
       <div class="span7">
         <strong><%= friend.name %></strong><br />
            <%if friendship.pending? %>
            <em>Friendship is pending.</em> <%=link_to "Delete request", edit_user_friendship_path(friendship) %>.
            <% end %>
            <% if friendship.requested? %>
                <em>Friendship requested.</em> <%=link_to "Accept Friendship", edit_user_friendship_path(friendship) %>.
            <% end %>
            <% if friendship.accepted? %>
                <em>Friendship started <%= friendship.updated_at %>.</em> <%= link_to "Update friendship", edit_user_friendship_path(friendship) %>.
            <% end %>
           </div>
       </div>
   <% end %>
```

Comment: A better way to approach Friendship handling is using the Amistad gem (https://github.com/raw1z/amistad) rather than reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, indeed, it has to do with that

```
mutual_friendship.update_attribute(:state, 'accepted')
```

You are creating two entries in the UserFriendship table when you do

```
    friendship1 = create!(user: user1, friend: user2, state: 'pending')
    friendship2 = create!(user: user2, friend: user1, state: 'requested')
```

but you are only updating one of them when the request is accepted.

I've added a line to the accept method in the controller that should solve the problem... give it a try and let me know if it works

```
def accept
  @user_friendship = current_user.user_friendships.find(params[:id])
  @user_friendship.accept_mutual_friendship!
  @user_friendship.friend.user_friendships.find_by(friend_id: current_user.id).accept_mutual_friendship!
  flash[:success] = "You are now friends with #{@user_friendship.friend.name}"
  redirect_to user_friendships_path
end
```